# Regular expression to match string_numbers_T

Tags: regex

Regular expression to match string_numbers_T

My string can be n number of characters and any character also.
followed by it _ and followed by numbers followed by it _T

Please suggest regular expression to match this kind of string

Comment: It is pretty straightforward. Read any regex docs.

Answer (score 1):

It is very clear , try this :

```
[\d\w]+_\d+_T
```